# local migrations not showing up on heroku

Tags: heroku, django-models

I know this question has been asked before however, my issue is a bit different from those problems.
I am working on a project and added a few attributes to different models in different apps and I did migrations gradually. and everything worked fine.
I created a PR on a forked public branch and my client merged my branch into a testing branch.

Now the issue is that Heroku is not recognizing the migrations on the remote server.

I am using `sqlite3` on my local development environment and `PostgreSQL` on the `production environment`.

Is `Heroku` serving the sqlite3 or `PostgreSQL` on production? or what can be the main issue?

**NOTE** : I am added as a collaborator and can't pull the local changes to the remote server and hence can't deploy the local changes to remote server.

**UPDATE**

the result of `git remote -v`

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/tarot-testing.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/tarot-testing.git (push)
master  https://github.com/abubakarA-Dot/tarot_juicer.git (fetch)
master  https://github.com/abubakarA-Dot/tarot_juicer.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/abubakarA-Dot/tarot_juicer.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/abubakarA-Dot/tarot_juicer.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/enoren5/tarot_juicer.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/enoren5/tarot_juicer.git (push)
```

Comment: After Heroku is set up with git, if you have a build back established, that will handle the migrations automatically. The separate issue that needs to be resolved first is making sure your local git repo points to the correct remote GitHub repo and correct remote Heroku repo. To this end, please update your question with the output of: `$ git remote -v`

Comment: @Angeles89, the standard Python buildpack does _not_ handle migrations automatically. Are you talking about a specific third-party buildpack?

Comment: Hi @Chris, I mispoke. Thank you for correcting me. To clarify, as long as has the Heroku build pack linked to below is installed, Django migrations should automatically exectue when the buildpack is triggered by git push.

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python

Comment: This buildpack might be required as well if the Heroku project is using PostgreSQL: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/best-practices-pgbouncer-configuration

Comment: @Angeles89, I'm not sure where you're getting that idea from. Again, that build pack _does not_ automatically apply migrations when you deploy. A common pattern is to declare a `release` process in your `Procfile` to run migrations as part of the release process, but that buildpack does _not_ automate this. Why would a Python buildpack automate Django migrations? Lots of Python projects don't use Django.

Comment: touché @Chris: You got me again! To ensure local developement migrations are migrated remotely in the cloud, a `Procfile` should be configured as you outlined briefly and as expanded upon in the official Heroku docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#specifying-release-phase-tasks Installing a third party build pack such as this one (among others) would do the trick too: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/openbook-schrobe/heroku-buildpack-django-migrate

Comment: My remaining question for @Chris now is: In my personal (hobbyist, not professional) experience with Django, my projects are deployed to Heroku without a `release` line in my `Procfile` and I don't use third party build packs. Is it possible that during the deployment process Heroku handles migrations on its own? If so, can you fill in our knowledge gap here? Without a properly configured Procfile or third party buildpack, how is it that my projects just work? It can't be just magic.

Comment: Part of the initial question asked this at the end: "I am added as a collaborator and can't pull the local changes to the remote server and hence can't deploy the local changes to remote server." To resolve this separate (but somewhat related) issue with git, the original poster still needs to update their question with the output of `git remote -v`. We need to make sure their local git repo is pointing to the various correct remote locations.

Comment: @Angeles89, I'm not aware of anything that would run your migrations automatically in the absence of a `release` process if you are only using the official Python buildpack. Of course, you can run them manually after deploying, e.g. via `heroku run python manage.py migrate`. Are you using SQLite by any chance? That might give the appearance of migrations running automatically (it still does not do this) but it comes with a host of other problems.

Comment: OP, SQLite does not work properly on Heroku due to its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). It is common (but not required) to use PostgreSQL there. We can't tell you for sure what database your application is using, and if you are attempting to use SQLite, that might lead to the kind of situation you're in now. So, back to you: is your application trying to use SQLite, PostgreSQL, or something else on Heroku? Check your settings module.

Comment: hi @Chris I am using sqlite3 for development however PostgreSQL is on production and staging but it seems Heroku is not supporting the free PostgreSQL dyno since Nov 13. I faced the same issue for another client and I was able to fix the issue by just using a paid dyno e.g $5/month eco plan. But they have deleted the old data fro the remote database. to fix the issue, I used heroku run python manage.py migrate and it fixed my migrations issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@djangodeveloper and I are on the same team working on the same [project on GitHub](https://github.com/enoren5/tarot_juicer).

The three methods for migrating a db on Heroku discussed in the comments so far include:

1. Running `$ heroku run python manage.py migrate`
2. Adding some paramaters to the `Procfile`
3. Install a third party (unofficial) Buildpack

Here is one more method to consider (the one that I use):

4. Run a remote AWS Postgres db locally.

It's as straightforward as running:

```
(local venv) $ export DATABASE_URL='postgres://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/NAME'
```

You can locate the DATABASE_URL with all the right variables specified inside the Heroku dashboard after revealing the config vars. All you need to do to get it working is to copy and paste that config var into your shell within the quotes. For a more in-depth explanation of how to use this technique, you can view the documentation in our GitHub project’s README.md at the heading titled: “[#3. Handling db remote instances but locally](https://github.com/enoren5/tarot_juicer#3-handling-db-remote-instances-but-locally)”. Using this technique, after having exported the db in my local development environment, I ran:

```
(local venv) $ python manage.py migrate
Database Config: {'default': {'NAME': <redacted>, 'USER': <redacted>, 'PASSWORD': <redacted>, 'HOST': '<redacted>', 'PORT': 5432, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600, 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'}}
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, essays, generators, landings, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying essays.0007_auto_20221107_2032... OK
  Applying essays.0008_auto_20221108_0627... OK
  Applying generators.0004_generator_is_published... OK
  Applying generators.0005_alter_generator_is_published... OK
  Applying landings.0005_auto_20221107_1312... OK
  Applying landings.0006_auto_20221108_0627... OK
```

As you can see  in the output at the bottom, the database has now been migrated successfully. In the Django Admin Dashboard, I can see all the data was preserved. Although there are new issues with the `generators` web app which will need to be handled separately outside the scope of the OP’s original question. The `staging` version of the site otherwise is running beautifully now.

Back in September when Heroku began notifying their users that the free PostgreSQL and Hobby dynos were being phased out, I proactively moved both our `staging` and `production` PostgreSQL databases to `Basic` tiers costing $9.00/mo for each. I didn’t lose any data and the transition so far has been seamless.

While the OP in the comment section shared his experience with a different Heroku project with PostgreSQL becoming unavailable and encountering data loss, I can confirm that was never the case with this project.

To this end, have a look at this output:

```
$ heroku pg:info -a tarot-testing
=== DATABASE_URL, COPPER_TESTING_URL
Plan:                  Basic
Status:                Available
Connections:           8/20
PG Version:            14.6
Created:               2022-10-02 13:50 UTC
Data Size:             11.1 MB/10.00 GB (In compliance)
Tables:                28
Rows:                  351/10000000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Billing App:           tarot-prod
Add-on:                postgresql-lorem-2
```

As you can see, it was created on October 2nd (well before the change-over deadline at the end of November) and it is populated with some data.

Here is a screenshot from our project's Heroku Dashboard showing  further proof that our PostreSQL is online and configured properly:

[image]